# change element style depending on local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a toggle input, where staff can set whether they are in or out of the office. I am using local storage to save the state of the input. When I add more than one toggle input onto the page, each input's state can be changed but when I reload the page all inputs are the same due to the local storage set on the last input ( i.e all to out ).

How do I save each toggles state and use local storage to remember this?

CSS CODE

```
<style type="text/css">
    .toggle {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      width: 150px;
      height: 60px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 50px;
      overflow: hidden;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: red;
      transition: background-color ease 0.3s;
    }

    .toggle:before {
      content: "in out";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      width: 80px;
      height: 70px;
      top: -5px;
      left: -10px;
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 50%;
      font: 30px/70px Helvetica;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-indent: -40px;
      word-spacing: 85px;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
      white-space: nowrap;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      transition: all cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.5, 0.7, 1) 0.3s;
    }

    .toggle:checked {
      background-color: #4CD964;
    }

    .toggle:checked:before {
      left: 75px;
    }

    .toggle.in {
        background-color: #4CD964;
    }

    .toggle.in:before {
        left: 75px;
    }

</style>
```

HTML CODE

```
<input class="toggle" type="checkbox" />
<input class="toggle" type="checkbox" />
```

JQUERY CODE

```
var toggle = $('.toggle');
toggle.on('click', function(){
    if ( $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length === 0 ) {
        localStorage.setItem('result', 'out');
        $(this).removeClass('in');  
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('result', 'in');
        $(this).addClass('in');
    }
})

if ( localStorage.result === 'in' ) {
    toggle.addClass('in');
} else {
    toggle.removeClass('in');
}
```

Comment: You're always overwriteing the same place in your localstorage (`result`). You need to save them seperately or as a stringified object/array.

Comment: for best results use an `ID` for each input and pass your localStorage value for each input in an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because you're only saving a single state and applying it to all checkboxes. Therefore the state applied last will be given to all on the next load of the page.

To fix this it would make far more sense to use an array. You can then store the state of *every* checkbox and re-apply when the page next loads, something like this:

```js
var $toggles = $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
  var checkedStates = $toggles.map(function() {
    return this.checked;
  }).get();
  localStorage.setItem('checkedStates', JSON.stringify(checkedStates));
  $(this).toggleClass('in');
})

if (localStorage.getItem('checkedStates')) {
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkedStates')).forEach(function(checked, i) {
    $('.toggle').eq(i).prop('checked', checked).toggleClass('in', checked)
  });
}
```

```css
.toggle {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  transition: background-color ease 0.3s;
}

.toggle:before {
  content: "in out";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80px;
  height: 70px;
  top: -5px;
  left: -10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font: 30px/70px Helvetica;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-indent: -40px;
  word-spacing: 85px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.5, 0.7, 1) 0.3s;
}

.toggle:checked {
  background-color: #4CD964;
}

.toggle:checked:before {
  left: 75px;
}

.toggle.in {
  background-color: #4CD964;
}

.toggle.in:before {
  left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="toggle" type="checkbox" />
<input class="toggle" type="checkbox" />
```

As SO places limits on the access to localStorage in a snippet, please see this fiddle for a working example:

[**Example Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wepqn44u/)

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to add an identifier to your `checkboxes`. Each time a checkbox is `changed` overwrite the value in `localStorage` and retrieve on page load. Also, use an `array` to save it in `localStorage`, becasue it will be easier to work with native JS objects rather than comma separated string.

See below

**HTML**

```
<input name="chk1" class="toggle" type="checkbox" />
<input name="chk2" class="toggle" type="checkbox" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var toggle = $('.toggle');

function updateStorage() {
  var storage = [];
  toggle.each(function() {
    storage.push({
      name: $(this).attr('name'),
      checked: $(this).prop('checked'),
    })
  });
  localStorage.setItem('prefix-result', JSON.stringify(storage));
}

function loadStorage() {
  var storage = localStorage.getItem('prefix-result');
  storage = storage ? JSON.parse(storage) : [];
  storage.forEach(function (item) {
    $('input[name=' + item.name + ']').prop('checked', item.checked)
  })
}

loadStorage();
toggle.on('change', updateStorage);
```

In your current code, you are using single `key` to save both `values`. That may work if you add both `values` but won't work if you overwrite previous one.

Comment: even better to use an `ID` rather than the input's name as identifier

Comment: yes that is also a good identifier. But I guess, OP can work with the alternatives. :)

Comment: there are cases where you might have the same name in two or more inputs, using the input `id` is for me the best way to do something like this. I think that is the reason why `id` was added as HTML attribute.

Comment: I already agreed on your point. My point was just that OP can figure this out whether `name` will be sufficient or code need to be changed to work with `id` :)

Comment: Yes you are right it is in the OP's hands to determine this. In case this is user related information passing a user `identifier` e.g. full name in the `localStorage` object could also be another approach. For example `... {"johnDoe":"in"}...`.